# What's the definition of Lie bracket of two tensor in "Introduction to Classical Integrable Systems" pp. 14

Tags: notation, integrable-systems

I'm reading "Introduction to Classical Integrable Systems". In pp. 14 the proposition of r-matrices there's fomula like
$$\{L_1, L_2\} = [r_{12}, L_1] − [r_{21}, L_2]$$.

If my understand is correct, $L$ is a matrix (function on phase space), $L_{1},\,L_{2}$ and $r_{12},\,r_{21}$ are tensors of matrices, so how did Lie bracket of two tensor defined? any helps are appreciated

Comment: Do you mean the square brackets? Isn't that just matrix commutators $[A,B]=AB-BA$?

Comment: @HansLundmark yes I mean the square bracket. Is in this case product of two tensor well defined? say $A,B\in M_n \otimes M_n$.

Comment: I don't know why you are talking about tensors. Aren't all quantities just matrix-valued functions on the phase space? (So that $AB$ is just usual matrix multiplication.)

Comment: Say it's possible to treat $r$ as rank $n^2$ matrix and in this sence product make sence? I'll try to understand that